# Как сохранить текст в переменной?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qlineedit, qtabwidget

Подскажите, как можно сохранить введенные данные в `QLineEdit`? 
Необходимо переключаться между вкладками чтобы текст в каждой отдельной вкладке сохранялся в поле ввода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, \
    QLabel, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout, \
    QVBoxLayout, QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import Qt


class Mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        example_layout = QVBoxLayout(centralwidget)

        pbs = QHBoxLayout()
        pb1 = QPushButton("1")
        pb2 = QPushButton("2")
        pbs.addWidget(pb1)
        pbs.addWidget(pb2)
        example_layout.addLayout(pbs)

        pics = QVBoxLayout()
        pic1 = QLabel("1")
        pic2 = QLabel("2")
        pics.addWidget(pic1)
        pics.addWidget(pic2)
        pictures = [pic1,pic2]

        comments_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        le1 = QLineEdit()
        le2 = QLineEdit()
        comments_layout.addWidget(le1)
        comments_layout.addWidget(le2)

        self.formlayout = QFormLayout()
        self.formlayout.setLayout(0, QFormLayout.LabelRole, pics)
        self.formlayout.setLayout(0, QFormLayout.FieldRole, comments_layout)
        example_layout.addLayout(self.formlayout)
        example_layout.addLayout(self.formlayout)

        pb1.clicked.connect(
            lambda pb=pb1, pc=pictures: self.action1(pb, pictures))
        pb2.clicked.connect(
            lambda pb=pb2, pc=pictures: self.action2(pb, pictures))


    def action1(self,pb,laybels):
        sl = ['не 1', 'не 2']
        for i in laybels:
            i.setText(sl.pop(0))


    def action2(self,pb,laybels):
        sl = ['1', '2']
        for i in laybels:
            i.setText(sl.pop(0))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])
    w = Mainwindow()
    w.show()
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов решения вашей задумки
реализуется через виджет `QTabWidget`.

Класс [**QTabWidget**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html) предоставляет набор виджетов с вкладками.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text1, text2):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.pic_1 = QLabel(text1)
        self.pic_2 = QLabel(text2)
        self.lineEdit_1 = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit_2 = QLineEdit()
        
        form_layout = QFormLayout(self)
        form_layout.addRow(self.pic_1, self.lineEdit_1)
        form_layout.addRow(self.pic_2, self.lineEdit_2)        
        

class Mainwindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        
        self.widget_1 = Widget("1", "2")      
        self.widget_2 = Widget("не 1", "не 2")
        
        tab = QTabWidget()
        tab.addTab(self.widget_1, '1')
        tab.addTab(self.widget_2, '2')
        
        grid = QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        grid.addWidget(tab)
        
        
Stylesheet = '''
QTabWidget::tab-bar {
    alignment: center;
}
QTabBar::tab {
    color: #EDDBC0;        
    background: #B73E3E;
    min-width:  70px;
    min-height:  20px;
    border: 2px solid #EDDBC0;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
QTabBar::tab:hover {
    color: #DBC8AC;
    background: #DD5353;    
}
QTabBar::tab:selected {
    color: #DD5353;
    background: #DBC8AC;    
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet) 
    window = Mainwindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как всегда, благодарю!

Comment: Подскажите, в данном виджете есть возможность открепить кнопки от QTabWidget? что бы они были в другом месте?

Comment: @Rett_oo https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#public-types , https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#TabPosition-enum . Если у вас возникают другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, приведите пример вашего кода и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать.